# Windows Phone 8.1 view files (word, excel) inside the App

Tags: excel, ms-word, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a control to view files like Word, Excel inside the app without opening another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a web browser control to renter text but it won't be properly formatted and for others you would require to create a custom viewer as there is no in built control. 
And if you try to open excel or word files in external apps it will by default open in native apps as it reserved by microsoft which cant be used by other apps.